# Un « pensez-y-bien » : l'emploi en substantif est-il usuel ou régional ?

Tags: québec, origine-ou-raison, substantivation

Le « *pensez-y[-]bien* » (n.m.) est un emploi en substantif d'une construction avec un verbe conjugué (comme le [*qu'en dira-t-on*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/quen-dira-t-on/65628?q=qu%27en%20dira-t-on#64885)), signifiant que ce qui est ainsi désigné est une option pouvant avoir des conséquences, positives ou négatives, et on nous invite donc à la réflexion sur le sujet afin de faire un choix éclairé. Par exemple, dans un [document](http://www.rrq.gouv.qc.ca/fr/flashretraiteqc/Pages/capsule_retraite_053.aspx) d'information au Québec, on peut trouver le titre « *L'hypothèque inversée : un pensez-y-bien!* ». On aurait possiblement pu se passer de déterminant et de *bien* (*pensez-y [bien] !*), ou dire simplement (que c'est) *matière à réflexion*...

Aucun des dictionnaires consultés n'en traite (*[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/penser), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/penser/59270), Wikébec, La Parlure, DHLF*). Sur *Books* on obtient avec l'expression des [résultats](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pensez%20y%20bien%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=6vOvVonFFqXbjgTe4bboCw#lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&q=%22pensez-y%20bien%22) d'il y a des siècles traitant de religion.<sup>1</sup>

---

- Est-ce un tour usuel compris de tous (vu sa proximité avec l'impératif sans déterminant) ; est-ce un emploi propre au Québec ?
- Y a-t-il un lien à faire entre l'origine de l'expression, le cas échéant, et l'emploi dans ces ouvrages religieux ou leur format ?
- Si c'est seulement usuel au Québec, a-t-on ailleurs une nominalisation d'une phrase similaire et de sens équivalent ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Utilisé comme [titre](https://books.google.com/books?id=k52lZC1d6YMC&dq=%22pensez-y%20bien%22&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=%22pensez-y%20bien%22&f=false), ou comme *type* de livre : [*livre de pensez-y bien*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KMkWAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22pensez-y%20bien%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk25225dfKAhVssIMKHVfkCVkQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q&f=false), une forme de recueil de morale religieuse chrétienne (?). Les auteurs semblent en être des religieux français du 17<sup>e</sup> au 19e<sup>e</sup> (surtout des jésuites : [Paul de Barry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_de_Barry), [Sabatier des Castres](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Sabatier_de_Castres), [Barthélemy Baudrand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barth%C3%A9lemy_Baudrand), Pierre-Grégoire Labiche de Reignefort, [Jean Brignon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Brignon)).</sub>

Comment: le dico de l'Académie français, septième édition (1884), cite Mme de Stael pour l'usage. C'est aussi signalé comme étant ***familier*** dans le CNRTL.  Mais, il cite Proust: "Nous n'avons de cesse que nous puissions expérimenter si la fière jeune fille du bord de la mer, si la vendeuse à cheval sur le qu'en-dira-t-on (...) ne sont pas susceptibles, à la suite de manèges adroits de notre part, de laisser fléchir leur attitude rectiligne." (Proust, Prisonn., 1922, p. 142).Je me demande si "pensez-y-bien" peut se lire comme familier. Je ne le pense pas.

Comment: Que c'est jolie: "la vendeuse à cheval sur le qu'en-dira-t-on" Proust, c'est trop. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uniquement pour répondre au premier point, en France (du moins pour mon cas), je comprends tout à fait l'expression, l'utilise et l'ai déjà entendu plusieurs fois.

Comment: Merci, c'est donc sans doute un simple tour qu'un francophone comprend naturellement. Je ne comprends pas pourquoi le _qu'en dira-t-on_ est documenté et pas ce genre de tour... c'est la raison pour laquelle j'ai pensé que c'était régional...

Comment: Je sélectionne la réponse. Il est possible que le _livre de pensez-y bien_ ne soit en fait qu'une preuve que le tour est naturel depuis longtemps, et non pas qu'il y ait une sémantique spécifique qui y soit rattachée. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas d'entrée dans le dictionnaire de l'application *Antidote*, un produit québécois, mais son module correcteur l'indique comme étant un québécisme. Curieux, puisque cette expression semble être connue ailleurs dans le monde francophone.

Comment: Je viens de noter que l'application Antidote est d'origine québécoise.Merci.

Comment: La phrase semble connue et compréhensible, mais son utilisation comme un substantif semble bien être un québécisme, si l'on en croit les réponses ici.

Answer (score 1):

En tant que francophone de France, je comprends cette expression mais lorsque je l'ai rencontrée pour la première fois je l'ai immédiatement "ressentie" comme un québécisme.